# zen cart + ckeditor set defaults for toolbar item

Tags: ckeditor, zen-cart

I have ckeditor installed and am using this as the default editor in zen cart when adding products.  For just about every product I have an iframe which displays the products external page.  Every time I add an iframe I have to set the width, height, alignment, scroll bars and border.

My question is: is there a way that I can configure ckeditor so that I can set defaults for these values?

Comment: Is the iframe in ckeditor? or are you adding the iframe through ckeditor?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the iframe through a dialog box from ckeditor, they provide a great article on setting default values here: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Default_Field_Values